# Null pointer exception while initializing listener

Tags: spring, hibernate

```
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'PurchaseAccount': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

can u tell me y this exception is  caused?

Answer (score 1):

... How about you provide some more information. There is not way for anyone to know what is wrong with your code when you don't give any. Please also let us know what have you done already to try to solve your problem.

Comment: @ScareletMerlin A small suggestion, This is not the answer. Future visitor might get confused. Please put this in comment section.

Comment: my apologies, I wasn't aware I could post comments on the question by now.